# JQuery Show Hide Multiple Div Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, function, optimization

I need to develop a News page with 3 articles that can be hidden or showed one by one, by means of 2 buttons: "Show more news" and "Show less news"
Each article must be hidden/displayed by clicking the relevant button only once, starting from the last article (at the bottom page) to the first one (top of page). HTML:

```
<!-- Articles-->
<article id="art-1" class="row" >My first Art</article>
<article id="art-2" class="row art" >My second Art</article>
<article id="art-3" class="row art" >My last Art</article>

<!--Buttons-->
<button class="button-grey" id="show-less-news1">Show Less</button>
<button class="button-grey" id="show-less-news2">Show Less</button>
<button class="button-grey" id="show-less-news3">Show Less</button>
<button class="button-grey" id="show-more-news1">Show More</button>
<button class="button-grey" id="show-more-news2">Show More</button>
<button class="button-grey" id="show-more-news3">Show More</button>
```

I managed to do this with JQuery but the code is extremely verbose and I need 6 buttons instead of 2, but I believe there must be a simplier way to get the same result with a less complex code. This is the JQuery code:

```
$("#show-more-news1").css({display:'none'});
$("#show-more-news2").css({display:'none'});
$("#show-more-news3").css({display:'none'});
$("#show-less-news1").css({display:'none'});
$("#show-less-news2").css({display:'none'});
    //function 1 less
$("#show-less-news3").click(function(){
$("#art-3").hide(400);
$("#show-less-news3").hide();
$("#show-more-news3").show();
$("#show-less-news2").show();
});
    //function 2 less
$("#show-less-news2").click(function(){
$("#art-2").hide(400);
$("#show-less-news2").hide();
$("#show-more-news3").hide();
$("#show-less-news1").show();
$("#show-more-news2").show();
});
    //function 3 more
$("#show-more-news3").click(function(){
$("#art-3").show(400);
$("#show-more-news3").hide();
$("#show-less-news2").hide();
$("#show-less-news3").show();
});
    //function 3 less
$("#show-less-news1").click(function(){
$("#art-1").hide(400);
$("#show-less-news1").hide();
$("#show-more-news2").hide();
$("#show-more-news1").show();
});
    //function 2 more
$("#show-more-news2").click(function(){
$("#art-2").show(400);
$("#show-more-news2").hide();
$("#show-less-news1").hide();
$("#show-less-news2").show();
$("#show-more-news3").show();
});
    //function 1 more
$("#show-more-news1").click(function(){
$("#art-1").show(400);
$("#show-more-news1").hide();
$("#show-less-news1").show();
$("#show-more-news2").show();
});
```

Some CSS:

```
  article {
  position: realtive;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float:left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.button-grey {
  display: block;
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  float:right;
}
```

Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvRBqN). Can someone help me to get the same result with a better code?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your HTML with only two buttons and identical CSS
The following JS works for better for me:

```
Javascript:


var newsDepth = 3;
var maxNewsDepth = 3;

$('#show-more-news').hide();


$('#show-more-news').click( function () {
  (newsDepth < maxNewsDepth ) && newsDepth++;
  $('#art-' + newsDepth).show();
  $('#show-less-news').show();
  if (newsDepth == maxNewsDepth) $('#show-more-news').hide();
});

$('#show-less-news').click( function () {
  ( newsDepth > 1 ) && newsDepth--;
  $('#art-' + (newsDepth + 1)).hide();
  $('#show-more-news').show();
   if (newsDepth == 1) $('#show-less-news').hide();
});
```

HTML

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Articles-->
<article id="art-1" class="row">My first Art</article>
<article id="art-2" class="row art">My second Art</article>
<article id="art-3" class="row art">My last Art</article>

<!--Buttons-->
<button class="button-grey" id="show-less-news">Show Less</button>
<button class="button-grey" id="show-more-news">Show More</button>
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGeEWL) for you

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I need to load all the article at the document load, in your code only the first art is loaded and both buttons shows.

Comment: Ok, Works fine, I just change "newsdept" to 0 in"show less" function to hide all the art.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a better version in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doonrhvr/6/).

HTML:

```
<!-- Articles-->
<div id="articles">
<article id="art-1" class="row">My first Art</article>
<article id="art-2" class="row art">My second Art</article>
<article id="art-3" class="row art">My last Art</article>
</div>

<!--Buttons-->
<button class="button-grey" id="show-less">Show Less</button>
<button class="button-grey" id="show-more" style="display: none">Show More</button>
```

JS:

```
    var allArticles = $('#articles article');
var visibleCount = 3;

$('#show-less').on('click', function() {
    // no more articles to hide
    if (visibleCount == 0) return;
    // hide the previous one
    $(allArticles[--visibleCount]).hide();

    // Show the more button
    $('#show-more').show();
    // hide the less button
    if (visibleCount == 0)
        $('#show-less').hide();
});

$('#show-more').on('click', function() {
    if (visibleCount == allArticles.length) return;
    // show the next article
    $(allArticles[visibleCount++]).show();

    // Show the less button
    $('#show-less').show();
    // hide the more button
    if (visibleCount == allArticles.length)
        $('#show-more').hide();
});
```

Comment: It works, similar to the Tim answer, but with a DIV added. Definitively, I need to improve my JS skills. Thanx a lot!